# Shipping weight Calculation

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the shipping price based on the product weight.

- Shipping Price $1 Weight 0-.5
- Shipping Price $2 Weight .6-1
- Shipping Price $3 Weight 2-3
- Shipping Price $4 Weight 4-5
- Shipping Price $5 Weight 6-10
- Shipping Price $6 Weight 11-25.

If I enter a weight between 1 and 10, the shipping price shows incorrectly. How do I fix these errors?

```js
function sprice() {
  let a = 0.5;
  let b = 1;
  let c = 3;
  let d = 5;
  let e = 10;
  let f = 25;

  let g = 1; //0-.5
  let h = 2; //.6-1
  let i = 3; //2-3
  let j = 4; //4-5
  let k = 5; //6-10
  let l = 6; //11-25

  let z = 0;
  let inc = 0;

  let p = document.getElementById("number").value;
  let s = 25;

  while (p > 0) {
    if (p <= a) {
      z += g;
    }
    if (p <= b) {
      z += h;
    }
    if (p <= c) {
      z += i;
    }
    if (p <= d) {
      z += j;
    }
    if (p <= e) {
      z += k;
    }
    if (p <= f) {
      z += l;
    }
    ++inc;
    let y = inc * z;
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "$" + y;
    p -= s;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter Weight:<input type="text" id="number" name="number" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="get" onclick="sprice()" />
</form>
</br>
<p>Shipping Price:<span id="ans"></span></p>
```

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names. What are `a`, `z` `inc` etc.?

Comment: Which erros shall be fixed?

Comment: @Reporter. if I enter product weight  27 means, split the weight into two. one is 25 and another one is 7. shipping price for this is $6 and $5. I need a total shipping price is $11

Comment: @Taxel variable name is not problem

Comment: @yuvaraj what do you mean by you split `27` into `25` and `7`? `25 + 7 = 32` !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your logic here, creating a function `getShippingPrice()` to get the shipping price for a given weight, then adding to the total price until all the weight is accounted for:

```js
function sprice()
{  
    let weight = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
    let s = 25;
    
    let totalPrice = 0;
    while (weight > 0) {
       totalPrice += getShippingPrice(weight);
       weight -= s;
    }    
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "$" + totalPrice;      
}

function getShippingPrice(weight) {
    if (weight <= 0.5 ) return 1;
    if (weight <= 1 )   return 2;
    if (weight <= 3 )   return 3;
    if (weight <= 5 )   return 4;
    if (weight <= 10 )  return 5;
    return 6;
}
```

```html
<form>  
Enter Weight:<input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>  
<input type="button" value="get" onclick="sprice()"/>  
</form> </br>   

<p>Shipping Price:<span id="ans"></span></p>
```

Comment: thankyou :). this is the very simplest way.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

Logic

- Check if user input is greater than 25
- If yes take the quantity as 25 or else take the same value of user input
- Calculate the value using if-else if conditions as mentioned in your question
- Decrement 25 from the user input.
- Run the logic in the loop till the user input is less than zero.

The issue that you had was you had to use `else if` instead of simple `else` because if you enter a value, say `0.1`, it satisfies all the if conditions. And the sum will be wrong. Also, you don't have to multiply your increment index with the same like `y = (inc*z);`. You just need to keep on adding the sum in a loop decrementing 25 each time while executing the loop.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function sprice() {
  let a = 0.5; let b = 1; let c = 3; let d = 5; let e = 10; let f = 25;

  let g = 1; //0-.5
  let h = 2; //.6-1
  let i = 3; //2-3
  let j = 4; //4-5
  let k = 5; //6-10
  let l = 6; //11-25

  let z = 0;

  let userInput = +document.getElementById("number").value;
  let s = 25;
  let quantity = 0;

  while (userInput > 0) {
    quantity = userInput > s ? s : userInput;
    if (quantity <= a) {
      z += g;
    } else if (quantity <= b) {
      z += h;
    } else if (quantity <= c) {
      z += i;
    } else if (quantity <= d) {
      z += j;
    } else if (quantity <= e) {
      z += k;
    } else if (quantity <= f) {
      z += l;
    }
    userInput -= s;
  }
  document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "$" + z;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter Weight:<input type="text" id="number" name="number" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="get" onclick="sprice()" />
</form> </br>

<p>Shipping Price:<span id="ans"></span></p>
```

Comment: if I enter  weight is 27 shipping is shown $0

Comment: @yuvaraj updated the answer. please check

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much more clean, reliable and scalable solution. I think the code is fairly simple so I won't explain it. But if you don't understand anything feel free ask me :)

```js
// Add more categories if you need
const categories = [{
    price: 1,
    range: [0, 0.5]
  },
  {
    price: 2,
    range: [0.6, 1]
  },
  {
    price: 3,
    range: [2, 3]
  },
  {
    price: 4,
    range: [4, 5]
  },
  {
    price: 5,
    range: [6, 10]
  },
  {
    price: 6,
    range: [11, 25]
  },
];

const [priceForMaxWeight, maxWeight] = categories.reduce(
  ([maxPrice, maxWeight], category) => {
    const [min, max] = category.range;
    if (min < 0 || max < 0 || min === max || min > max)
      throw new Error(`Invalid range: [${min}, ${max}]`);
    return max > maxWeight ? [category.price, max] : [maxPrice, maxWeight];
  }, [Infinity, -Infinity]
);

function getPrice(weight) {
  const isInRange = (value, [min, max]) => value >= min && value <= max;

  for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    const {
      price,
      range
    } = categories[i];
    if (isInRange(weight, range)) return price;
  }

  throw new Error(`Weight: ${weight} doesn't fall into any category.`);
}

function calculatePrice(weight) {
  if (weight < 0) throw new Error(`Invalid weight: ${weight}`);

  if (weight > maxWeight)
    return priceForMaxWeight + calculatePrice(weight - maxWeight);
  return getPrice(weight);
}

// Interacting with dom
const calculateButton = document.getElementById("btn");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const weightInput = document.getElementById("weight");

calculateButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const weight = Number(weightInput.value);
  result.innerText = calculatePrice(weight) + "$";
});
```

```html
<p>Enter Weight:</p>
<input id="weight" type="number" min="0" /><br />
<button id="btn">Calculate Price</button>

<p>Price: <span id="result">0$</span></p>
```

Comment: thankyou this is explained deeply. thankyou:)

Comment: Hey @yuvaraj, If any of the answers posted above solves your problem then you should mark one accepted. Also an up-vote would be highly  appreciated <3